# Using tokens derived from \let

Tags: tex-core

It seems that tokens that are derived from `\let` command can't always be used literally. The following fails. I want to test if the next character is a numerical constant. Of course, the test is not complete; I am only asking a question here.

```
\newcount\cnta
\def\gobble#1{}
\def\cmda{\futurelet\next\cmdb}
% \next is unabsorbed but remains as character 2. \gobble is meant to gobble 2.
\def\cmdb{\cnta0\next\space\gobble}
\cmda 2
\showthe\cnta
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is? There are many similar instances eg \egroup is \let equal to } but \def\a{\egroup} and \def\a{}} are not at all the same.

Comment: `\next` is here not expandable and therefore ends the *read number* mode. You are right, such implicit tokens are not generally interchangeable with the explicit tokens. The will case the same result if they are typeset but not in most other cases. For example you can't use an implicit token inside `\csname ..\endcsname`. I had this issue with the `tikz-timing` parser.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I thought \, { and } are special cases.

Comment: well it depends if you are a cup half full or cup half empty kind of person. You could say { is a special case and the syntax for a literal <number> is special and the syntax for a unit is special and..., or you could say they are all just parsed "the TeX way"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `\cmda 2`
2. `\futurelet\next\cmdb 2`

   This is equivalent to
3. `\let\next 2\cmdb 2`

   Now `\next` has meaning "The character 2" and the `\let` is removed.
4. `\cnta0\next\space\gobble 2`

   `\cnta` starts an assignment, and `\next`, which is unexpandable and not a `<digit>`, ends the search for a number. So `\cnta=0` is performed, `\next` is passed on for execution as it will be the space resulting from `\space` and `\gobble` gobbles 2.

TeX does *macro* expansion when searching for a number, but after `\let\next=2`, `\next` is *not* a macro. Also an assignment such as

```
\cnta=\next
```

would be illegal after `\let\next=2` (or using `\futurelet`, which is equivalent); see the syntax for `<number>` in the TeXbook, page 269: implicit character tokens can't be used.

Comment: The above is all true of course, but `2` isn't a macro either but `\cnta02` would consume the `2` so not being a macro isn't enough of a reason: it's just that the final (after macro expansion) syntax for numbers includes digit character tokens and TeX registers, but not tokens `\let` equal to characters.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added something.

Comment: So, how could the original task "I want to test if the next character is a numerical constant." be performed? Compare `\next` with all digits consecutively using `\if`?

Comment: @StephanLehmke yes or depending what you want to do about leading digits, `\afterassigntment\foo\cnta0` might do something useful as it consumes all following digits, so if cnta is not 0 you ate a digit, if it is zero you have to work harder

Comment: I thought about `\afterassignment` as well, but wouldn't it read more than one character, expand things etc?

Comment: Thanks. I think the key point here is "TeXbook, page 269: implicit character tokens can't be used for counter assignment." Actually, my test revolves around `\afterassigntment` but I didn't want to grab the number. The approach I have now used is to "grab and release".